# flutter ElevatedButton problems

Tags: flutter, dart

Here is my code

```
ElevatedButton(

            child : Text ("Continue"),
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();

                KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(context);
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, LoginSuccessScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
```

`ElevatedButton` isn't a function. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to match an existing function, or define a method or function named 'ElevatedButton'.
The name `ElevatedButton` is defined in the libraries `package:fitnessapp/components/elevated_button.dart` and `package:flutter/src/material/elevated_button.dart (via package:flutter/material.dart)`. (Documentation)  Try using 'as prefix' for one of the import directives, or hiding the name from all but one of the imports.

"How i can fix this problem" ?

Comment: It seems you have component called `ElevatedButton`. Use `as` keyword like below. `import 'package:fitnessapp/components/elevated_button.dart' as CustomElevatedButton;`

Answer (score 2):

In the dart file you use, there are 2 imported files that have the same name, so it does not know which to use. Either remove one of them or name the libraries:

```
import 'package:fitnessapp/components/elevated_button.dart' as MyButton;
```

Then whenever you want to use something from this file, you can call it like:

`MyButton.ElevatedButton()`;